# Identify Dell Server Motherboard

Tags: dell, hardware, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell Poweredge 2850 server and yesterday it died. It seems like motherboard is the culprit.

I'm trying to get a replacement now, but that is where it gets a little bit confusing. If I enter my service tag into Dell Parts Search engine, it gives me a choice of at least 3 motherboard part numbers: Dell Part# HH715, Dell Part# HH719, Dell Part# T7916. On  ebay, where I'm planning on buying the replacement MoBo, there's even more variations. I looked at the motherboard itself and I can't seem to find any model number like that on it.

Is there a way to find out motherboard model number? Or should I just get any of the MB models that Dell offers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the service tag to display the original system configuration. It should have a Dell part number for the mother board and may even have a model number.

Answer (score 0):

Call Dell to get the build sheet on your machine with the Service Tag.  They will be able to tell you exactly what you need. The model should be printed on the motherboard.  I have seen them printed all over the place, no specific place to look.